# Is there a jQuery plugin for Dot language file visualization?

Tags: jquery-plugins, graphviz, dot

Is there a jQuery plugin for displaying [Dot files](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/DotLanguageDirected.svg/168px-DotLanguageDirected.svg.png) live in the browser as specified [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language)?

I've seen a proof of concept at [Visual Politics](http://visualpolitics.net/admin/graphviz_test), but it doesn't seem to fully support the Dot language as even -- doesn't display correctly.

Any libraries out there I could have a look at for this?

I need to implement network graphs in the browser from dot files loaded via Ajax (rather than server side generated PNGs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out Canviz: http://code.google.com/p/canviz/

Demos are located here: http://www.ryandesign.com/canviz/

Comment: That actually looks solid. I'm just going to see what else comes in. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I was looking for the same answer, I found "viz.js" providing a java script version of GraphViz for DOT (see https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js).

Using this, I build myself **WP GraphViz**, a plugin for WordPress (see http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-graphviz/).

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on this for almost a week.

There are three different implementations:

1.Render svg in simple js, no needs install of graphviz

jquery.graphviz.svg https://github.com/mountainstorm/jquery.graphviz.svg

jQuery plugin to make Graphviz SVG output more interactive and easier to navigate.  Makes it easy to have features like:

- Highlight nodes/edges
- Zoom in/out
- Graph navigation - select linked nodes
- Fancy UI tooltips; bootstrap supported out the box
- Move things forward/back in the graph

Have a look at the demo: https://cdn.rawgit.com/mountainstorm/jquery.graphviz.svg/master/demo.html

2.Based on d3.js

```
<https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre-d3>  d3.js + dagre

    <https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre>  pure js library
```

or:

```
<https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz>  d3.js + graphviz c++ build

    <https://github.com/hpcc-systems/hpcc-js-wasm>  build graphviz 2.47
```

3.server side call graphviz to generate svg file.

```
<http://viz-js.com/>

    <https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js>

<https://github.com/dreampuf/GraphvizOnline>
```